# Android UnsatisfiedLinkError native method not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm building native app. When I wanna to start this app logcat says

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: SDLThread
Process: org.libsdl.app, PID: 1560
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity.nativeInit:()V
at org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity.nativeInit(Native Method)
at org.libsdl.app.SDLMain.run(SDLActivity.java:421)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Library loaded correctly.

```
Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.libsdl.app-1/libSDL2.so 0xb1ddc818
Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.libsdl.app-1/libSDL2.so 0xb1ddc818
Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.libsdl.app-1/libmain.so 0xb1ddc818
Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.libsdl.app-1/libmain.so 0xb1ddc818
No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.libsdl.app-1/libmain.so 0xb1ddc818, skipping init
```

In main.so I can see

```
T Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit
```

Comment: Please add the class and function headers from the Java code, and the function headers from the native code.

Comment: Was the same class loader used to load both the `org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity` class and the `libmain.so` library?  The VM won't search the library unless they match.  See also `dvmResolveNativeMethod()` in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/Native.cpp, particularly when it gets to  `findMethodInLib()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use SDL_Main as entry point need to call

```
void SDL_SetMainReady(void)
```

before SDL_Init()
In detail there: http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady